# sql anywhere trigger needs parameter

Tags: sqlanywhere

I had already found a fiew questions about triggers and parameters but no single one could solve my problem... the only thing I know is that its not good if triggers need parameters.

but I have 2 tables...e.g.

```
color    object
======   ======
red      pencil
green    knife
blue     pencil
yellow   pencil
red      knife


object      count
======      =====
pencil      3
knife       2
```

And I have a procedure which deletes for example the red pencil.
Now I want to make a trigger who decreases the number of pencils in the second table about one.

Respectively if i delete a knife the number of knifes should be decreased.

But now I have to say the trigger which object I have deleted.
How I can make this?... or is it better if I use instead the trigger a procedure which is called by the procedure which deletes the object?
thank you

Comment: No, triggers don't need parameters. You need two triggers (one after deletion, one after modification). You don't choose which table the trigger will affect; you use separate triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use a trigger to delete a row, most of the information in that row will be stored in a special table called "deleted" (certain data types such as ntext, text, and image aren't). But for your purposes, this should work.

```
Declare @Object nvarchar (50)
Select @Object = [Object] from deleted
Update YourSecondTable set [Count] -= 1 where [Object] = @Object
```

Adjust as needed. Make sure you only call this trigger on delete and not update, since update also copies data to the deleted table.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/  <-- general overview FYI.

Answer (score 1):

ty @SEFL

the code for sql anywhere is a bit different but it is the same principle.
Here is the code that works for me:

```
 ALTER TRIGGER "deleteObject" AFTER DELETE
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."objects"
REFERENCING OLD AS oldData
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE summary
    SET count = count - 1
    WHERE object = oldData.object
END
```

here you access the deleted row with ***REFERENCING OLD AS oldData*** and then with ***oldData.object***